# npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`

Tags: node.js, npm

Error with npm install for my application in Ubuntu 16

```
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.0 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.0 install script 'node scripts/install.js'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the node-sass package,
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit you package.json to use "node-sass@^4.5.3", this version installs fine for me